# ESP32 LED driver circuit

Tags: esp32, uln2003

Is there anything majorly wrong with the below schematic? I'm still learning and I have followed the datasheet but feel like I'm missing something.

[image: Revised Schematic with changes recommended and addition of A3400 fets]

[image: LED driver circuit]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134155/discussion-on-question-by-robbrown92-esp32-led-driver-circuit).

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that finds this and has similar questions:

- Remember pull-up resistor on buttons;
- ULN2003: 150 mA limit per channel; better to use a FET such as AO3400.

Comment: > Remember pull-up resistor on buttons;
The ESP has internal pull-up resistors you can enable on it's GPIO. You can skip them if you want.